# WooCommerce returns number of products in category inconsistently

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On a WordPress site with WooCommerce I use this function to query for the number of products in a category

```
 $check_products = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'include' => $element->object_id ) );
```

This is inside a menu_walker class to add the number of products to the category name in a menu-option, like this `New Products (10)`. This site sells unique products, so after selling an item, the item is out of stock.

This works fine, but after installing WPML there is a difference in count. The site has a default language and a WPML translated version. When you buy something while using default language, the menu-option will show the correct adjusted number of products. Switch to the WPML translated version, and the number is unchanged (too high).

The same error happens when you buy something from the WPML translated version and then switch to the default language version.

How can the same function return a different value?

If already tried to clear/reset information in the Tools menu of WooCommerce but no luck yet.

Comment: I think maybe the problem is that once WPML is installed the products exist twice, once for each language. Can you confirm this? I think if they have a different ID on different languages, that means they do.

Comment: You are right, there are two records for every product. It is still weird when you browse to the category page, in either language, it shows the correct products. Also in the backend, it shows correct inventory for the products.

Comment: So in the backend it shows 0 products for both languages after you buy just from one? edit: when I say 0, I mean 0 in stock

Comment: Yes. I just checked the database termmeta table for both category IDs and found one has a `product_count_product_cat` setting of 5 (which is correct) and the other one shows 7. So that is the error, now all I have to find out how to get those synchronized :(

Comment: @LL thanks for your help. I now know that things will adjust correctly when pressing Terms Count in the 'faulty' language. Otherwise it won't work. Would you call this a bug of WooCommerce, or WPML

Comment: Glad I manageed to point you a bit, good luck with fixing it up :)

Answer (score 0):

After going back and forth with WPML support a few times, they were willing to escalate the issue to the 2nd line of support.

Will update this answer when there is news on the matter.

The issue in short:
When WooCommerce updates the `product_count_product_cat` entry of a category after a purchase, WPML doesn't notify WooCommerce to do the same for the other (translated) instances of the category.